# Scaling and Rotation of line segments

Tags: geometry

I have a question about mathematical equations and my code for scaling a line segment and rotating a line segment about a specific point.

Currently, I can draw two line segments and have them intersect.

What I want to do:

-After drawing my intersecting line segments, I want to be able to scale/extend the line up and down in realtime by clicking on the endpoint of line segment and dragging the line up or down in a straight line.

-Also, I would like to be able to rotate either of the two intersecting line segments about the intersection point by clicking on the endpoint of the line or the line itself and dragging it left or right.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public Vector2 ScaleLine(Vector2 intersectionPoint, Line line, Vector2 mousePosition)
{

    double lengthOfPointOneToPointTwo = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((line.point1.x - line.point2.x),2) + Math.Pow((line.point1.y - line.point2.y),2));
    double newPointOne =  line.point2.x + (line.point2.x - line.point1.x) / lengthOfPointOneToPointTwo  * (mousePosition.y - intersectionPoint.y);
    double newPointTwo = line.point2.y + (line.point2.y - line.point1.y) / lengthOfPointOneToPointTwo * (mousePosition.y - intersectionPoint.y);

    return new Vector2((float)newPointOne, (float) newPointTwo);

}

   //Shift coordinate system so that origin is at the point of rotation, do the rotation and then shift the coordinate system
   //back to original intersection poiint
   public Vector2 RotateLineAboutIntersectionPoint(Vector2 intersectionPoint, Line line, Vector2 mousePosition)
   {
       double angle = Math.Atan2(mousePosition.y - intersectionPoint.y, mousePosition.x - intersectionPoint.x);
       double newPointOne = (line.point1.x - intersectionPoint.x) * Math.Cos(angle) - (line.point1.y - intersectionPoint.y) * Math.Sin(angle) + intersectionPoint.x;
       double newPointTwo = (line.point1.x - intersectionPoint.x) * Math.Sin(angle) + (line.point1.y - intersectionPoint.y) * Math.Cos(angle) + intersectionPoint.y;

       return new Vector2((float)newPointOne,(float)newPointTwo);
   }
```

Do the formulas line up with the theory? Also, since this is happening in realtime by having the user drag the lines and not set value, is the logic for getting my mouse positions correct?

EDIT:

Here's how I derived my rotation formula with help previously: 
[Two line segments are intersecting... how do I rotate either line about the intersection point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192606/two-line-segments-are-intersecting-how-do-i-rotate-either-line-about-the-inte)

Comment: Just edited. I noticed something for rotation formula, when I set my first point of rotation to my mouse pointer, the second point of my line goes crazy. I can rotate my first point but how do I rotate my second point of my line along when the first one is rotated/dragged?

Comment: My first thought about this is that graphical user interface design at this level, where you have to figure out what the user is doing by tracking the coordinates of the mouse, is very difficult, at least at first. You have the double problem of trying to figure out whether the input functions are generating the parameters you want (e.g. scale factor and rotation) and whether the output functions are using those parameters correctly. If the display goes haywire you cannot always easily tell whether it's an input problem or an output problem.

Comment: A further thought is that it might help to write two programs at first, one of which tells you (using numerical output) how the movement of the mouse is being interpreted, and the other of which takes numerical input to decide how to redraw the figures on the screen. This way a problem with the input will be clearly indicated by the first program, but a problem with the output will be clearly indicated by the second program. When both programs are debugged you can merge them into the desired full-function program.