# Find every point of rotated about one rectangle point

Tags: geometry, rotations

I need some formulas to find every point of rectangle, which has been rotated **about one of his points**. I have access to:

- location of point about which the rectangle was rotated
- width and height of the rectangle
- rotation angle

This is an image which describes my problem (sorry for my afwul drawing):
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1jmu.png)

The formulas I need must be useful for any rotation angle.

Comment: A simple web search for rotation about an arbitrary point will give you more formulas for this than you can stand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two line segments are intersecting... how do I rotate either line about the intersection point?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192606/two-line-segments-are-intersecting-how-do-i-rotate-either-line-about-the-inte). Found duplicate by searching for "rotation about a point". Who'da thunk it.